How to create a class with updated private field using ByteBuddy?
I need to create a class with updated private field.
This is my code:
public class ByteBuddyTest {

    public static class Foo {

    }

    public static class Bar {

        private Foo foo;

        public Foo getFoo() {
            return foo;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Class<? extends Bar> clazz = new ByteBuddy()
            .subclass(Bar.class)
            .??? //LINE X
            .make()
            .load(ByteBuddyTest.class.getClassLoader(), ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.WRAPPER)
            .getLoaded();

        var bar1 = clazz
            .getDeclaredConstructor()
            .newInstance();
        System.out.println(bar1.getFoo());

    }
}

At line X I need to set a new instance of Foo to field Bar.foo for every instance of Bar. Please, note, that I need to create many instances of Bar, so I want to create a class with ByteByddy only once. Could anyone say how to do it?

If you need to create many instances of Bar, then why is it a static class?  Hacks like ByteBuddy should never be your first thought.  Why can't you do this through derivation?

@TimRoberts I used static classes only for this example. In real application "usual" classes are used.

You should think carefully before breaking encapsulation like this.  It can easily cause bugs.  That said, there are rare cases when it's necessary, e.g. to work around a bug in a legacy system you can't modify.
However, you don't need ByteBuddy for this, and I don't think it makes it easier.  You can do it with stock reflection.
I'm closing as a duplicate.

@MatthewFlaschen Thank you for your comment. But now, please, reopen this question. This question is about byte-buddy, but now about reflection. Do you see the difference? If I had used reflection, I would ask a question about reflection, wouldn't I? But I had to create a complex class with byte-buddy with many different features. I almost did it, except setting private field. So, this is not a duplicate. So, again, please, reopen the question.

"I had to create a complex class with byte-buddy with many different features".  That is key context that is not in the question.  Update your question to explain what you're using ByteBuddy for, then I will re-open it.

@MatthewFlaschen I clearly said in my question, the it was about byte-buddy. It is your fault that you (I don't know why) decided that answer about reflection can answer it. So, I won't update it.

Byte Buddy creates Java classes, and those classes will need to adhere to the same rules as if you wrote the class manually. As a result, you cannot set a private field from a subclass. You can therefore either: (a) make the field protected, or (b) redefine the class to add the code to the class that declares the field.
As for Byte Buddy, the easiest approach for you would be to use Advice:
class ConstructorAdvice {
  @Advice.OnMethodExit
  static void exit(Advice.Field(value = "foo", readOnly = false) Foo foo) {
    foo = new Foo();
  }
}

You would then apply this advice to all relevant constructors of the class in question, using visit.
